# California Prop 13 question

Tags: taxes

Can someone help me clarify how max property tax increase is calculated via prop 13?

Prop 13 limits it to 2% yearly.

Does this mean the tax increase can be a max of 1% of the 2% of the assessed value?

So a $1000000 home will have a max tax increase of 1000000*0.02*0.01= $200 per year?

Or is it just 2% of the assessed value, so max tax yearly increase is 1000000*0.02 = $20,000?

The second number seems crazy high, which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sense, first understand that Prop 13 was designed because property values in CA shoot up, but incomes do not follow. Many people bought a house for say $300k in the early 1990s, and within a decade, it had value of $1.5M+. Yet they do not make 5 times as much money, so property taxes can become unaffordable without a cap.

Thus, the cap is on the assessed value. As [explained here](https://www.californiataxdata.com/pdf/Prop13.pdf),

> Under Prop. 13, the property is assessed for tax
>   purposes only when it changes ownership. As long as the property is not sold,
>   **future increases in assessed value** are limited to an annual inflation factor of no
>   more than 2%.

So if the tax rate is 1% and your house has an assessed value of $100k, you have

Year 1 taxes = $100,000 * 0.01 = $1,000

Year 2 tax cap = $100,000 * 1.02 * 0.01 = $1,020

Year 3 tax cap = $100,000 * (1.02)^2 * 0.01 = $1,040.40